# VBA - Abrir uma página explorer, fazer uma pesquisa no google imagens, dar scrolldown até o fim da página e usar o console

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Estou desenvolvendo um módulo de VBA para abrir o google imagens, pesquisar "cimento", rolar a pagina pra baixo até o fim e então usar o console para dar input em alguns scripts em javscript.

O Código até agora está da seguinte forma:

```
Sub Google()
Dim IE As Object
Dim Pesquisa As String

Pesquisa = "cimento"

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate ("https://www.google.com/imghp?q=" & Pesquisa)
    While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4:
        DoEvents:
    Wend

    waittime (1000)

    SendKeys "~", True
    SendKeys "{PGDN}", True
    .document.parentwindow.execScript "javascript_code()", "JavaScript"

End With

End Sub

Function waittime(ByVal milliSeconds As Double)
    Application.Wait (Now() + milliSeconds / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000)
End Function
```

Contudo, a página não rola para baixo, o que é de suma importancia para que o script funcione. Procurei em vários lugares como fazer isso, mas todos voltam para esta mesma função Sendkeys. Se alguem tiver alguma sugestão sobre como dar input no console do explorer, eu agradeço também. Não pude testar esse método ainda.

Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde, já tiver um problema parecido com esse, acredito que esse artigo possa te ajudar. O código que está descrito abaixo funcionou no meu caso, recomendo você testar. Espero que tenha ajudado.

https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/531354-solved-launch-ie-browser-and-manage-vertical-scroll-bars.html

```
Sub LaunchIeAndManageVerticalScroll()
Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE& = 4&
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With ie
    .AddressBar = False
    .MenuBar = False
    .Toolbar = False
    .Width = 600&
    .Height = 750&
    .Left = 0&
    .Top = 0&
    .navigate "www.yahoo.com"
    .resizable = True
    While Not .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend
    .document.parentWindow.scroll 0&, 200&
    .Visible = True
End With
 Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Favor ler [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/42/75104) e editar a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado por esse link, irei elevar meu padrão de respostas.